# Allow Careers name in mixed case

Tags: feature-request, jobs, cv

The candidate name on the [public CV of Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) is currently in all upper case.

Can it be changed so it respects the one typed by the user (me) on the edit CV box?

That would be:

```
s/OSCAR REYES/Oscar Reyes
```

Comment: +1 I agree, I would never put my name in all caps at the top of my resume!  Small caps, *maybe*, but never all caps.

Comment: I don't know.  I think my resume title might be better fully capitalized than it is when I print my own version: "M. ADAM DAVIS, LORD AND MASTER OF ALL HE SURVEYS"... Hmmm... still a toss-up.

Answer (score 2):

While it doesn't affect me, I can see this being a problem for people such as McCormack which may also be capitalized as Mccormack depending on the person's preferences.

Having it all caps may result in employers scratching their heads wondering, "Should I address Mr. McCormack or Mr. Mccormack?"

Comment: Or e. e. cummings.

Comment: fortunately the employer view doesn't appear to have this issue--the employer view is mixed case

Comment: The employer that is using the career's interface.  But if someone comes through the public CV, they are still at a disadvantage.